# Create folders with unique names of filenames

Tags: bash, sort

I am trying to create folders from unique filenames. Here are the files:

```
T001
└── 20000101
    ├── 6_3D-MP-RAGE_97.dcm
    ├── 6_3D-MP-RAGE_98.dcm
    ├── 5_133_VOLUMES_99027.dcm
    ├── 5_133_VOLUMES_99028.dcm
    ├── 5_133_VOLUMES_99029.dcm
    ├── 5_133_VOLUMES_99030.dcm
    ├── 4_COR_3D_T1_MPR_1.dcm
    ├── 4_COR_3D_T1_MPR_107.dcm
```

I want bash magic to result in this:

```
T001
└── 20000101
    ├── 6_3D
        ├── 6_3D-MP-RAGE_97.dcm
        ├── 6_3D-MP-RAGE_98.dcm
    ├── 5_133
        ├── 5_133_VOLUMES_99027.dcm
        ├── 5_133_VOLUMES_99028.dcm
        ├── 5_133_VOLUMES_99029.dcm
        ├── 5_133_VOLUMES_99030.dcm
    ├── 4_COR
        ├── 4_COR_3D_T1_MPR_1.dcm 
        ├── 4_COR_3D_T1_MPR_107.dcm
```

And I have tried this code to extract folder names, but got stuck:

```
all_patterns=()
for file in sorted/folder/*/*
do
    name=${file##*/}
    pattern=`echo ${name} | cut -f1 -d '_'`
    all_patterns+=( "$pattern" )
done
```

Comment: What is the list of all delimiters (`-`,`_`,...)?

Comment: @RomeoNinov that's it (`-`,`_`)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to generate the directory names and create those directories:

```
cd  T001/20000101
for i in *
do
dname=$(echo $i|awk -F'[-_]' '{print $1_$2}')
mkdir -p $dname
mv "$i" $dname
done
```

Comment: @Quasímodo, I define both as delimiters

Comment: Yes, but what @Quasimodo is saying is that `foo-bar_baz` will end up in directory `foo_bar`: the delimiter is changed. Whether that matters or not  only the OP can tell us.

Comment: I get it. Let OP tell if this is important or not.

Comment: @RomeoNinov thanks for your answer, it works, but it's import that if a directory has  ```_``` like T_001 it will be changed to T001, and will create new one.